# Will rsync use delta coding even when I copy between local harddrives?

Tags: rsync

Is rsync using [delta coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_encoding) to reduce data transfer even when both of the directories I sync are on local harddrives (or just when copying over the network)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rsync` explicitly turns on the `--whole-file` option when doing a sync across filesystems as opposed to doing a sync between a network location and a filesystem. The delta transfer algorithm is designed to minimize network traffic at the cost of possible extra local IO traffic. It's faster to simply transfer the whole file locally than to read both files completely to find possible matches.

Note that rsync considers network mounts such as NFS as local, which also leads to less IO and hence less network traffic than reading the whole file at both ends, although it's best to let rsync do the network transfer if possible.